# Using cross-project version naming in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

If project **A** has a dependency on project **B** is it possible to use the *{build.vcs.number}* or another variable from **A** in **B**? So that a packaged version of **B** receives the same version as **A** for example.

*I'm using TeamCity 7.1.3*

Answer (score 1):

If A depends on B by artifact or snapshot dependency, then A can use any parameter available in B via %dep..% properties, but not vice versa, you can't use A parameters in B.